# Kafka: ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector' was not found

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka on the windows machine and I am trying to use **file-source** connector to produce content from a file to Kafka topic. Firstly I started zookeeper and afterward Kafka server while starting Kafka Standalone Connector ([at step 3](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/apache-kafka-connector/)) I am getting lots of WARNING, ReflectionsException & Error logs.

[image]

[image]

I have few doubts here:
1. do I need to add some jar files? 
2. In Kafka dir under libs folder there are some jar files, do I need to add those to the classpath?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: which java version do you have installed?

Comment: I suggest you use Filebeat, Fluentd, Logstash, etc for this. File source connector is only intended for development purposes only, and you can just cat a file into the console producer as a working alternative

Comment: Hi @BogdanSucaciu I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore messages about the class loader.

The real error message is your file cannot be found

There are a few JIRA issues about fixing the quoting around the Java variables in the batch scripts, which would fix classpath and jar lookup issues, but as I commented, better to use a production-grade log forwarder to read files to Kafka